# Color on a JVSpeedButton

Tags: delphi

In a project I need a button/ buttons with 2 lines

```
eg:  
    CLIENTS/
    CUSTOMERS
```

and a backgroundcolor on the button.

I have after a long, long search finally found that a TJVspeedButton can have 2 lines, and a Color-attribute.

But when I set `TJVspeedButton1.Color := clRed;` in the Tform1.Create() it does not set the color to Red. I tried the `TJVspeedButton1.ParentColor := True;` 
still nothing happens.

I running D2010 Architect on a XP/sp3 and in the "uses" clause/line I have included XPMAN;

What can I do when I want to use both XPMan and JVSpeedButton(s) ?

Comment: XPMan has been obsolete for more than a decade. It was a workaround for the IDE not being able to properly add a manifest for Windows XP, and is no longer necessary. You can (and should) remove it from both your form and the uses clause. *Project->Options->Application->Enable Runtime Themes* does the same thing properly. Using runtime themes disables most drawing other than using themes, so trying to do both is going to be difficult for you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll do it immidiately.

Comment: Did you try ParentColor := false instead of true? Setting it to true means use the parent's color and ignore the color set on this component.

Comment: @Heffernan:  I did some research on the net. I could NOT find any references of JVspeedButton with and without Color (a lot on MULTILINE) , and THEN I asked.    Anyway I did some research on my (very) old hdd's and it appeared the TJANButton (downloaded years ago from TORRY.net)  had a TButton-component, which had both COLOR and MULTI-Line . So I downloaded it , installed it. And Heureka - it worked. It's a componet for D5 but works fine with D2010.